# Android Q make photos saved in getExternalFilesDir() visible in Gallery

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-10.0

All I want is that my app photos can be visible both in phone gallery and inside my app.

I want to show all previous images made from my app and do it like this (I removed some code about populating recyclerView to make it more readable):

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ivPhoto = findViewById(R.id.photo);

        photoPaths = new ArrayList<>();
        File directory = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
            for (File file : files) {
                photoPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
        if (photoPaths.size() > 0) {
            File file = new File(photoPaths.get(0));
            try {
                ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(file.getCanonicalPath());
                String text = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_EXIF_VERSION);
                Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPaths.get(0));
            ivPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
}
```

This method I use to take photo from camera:

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (photoFile == null) {
                return;
            }
            Uri photoURI;
            Uri photoURIQ;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues(2);
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

                photoURIQ = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURIQ);
            } else {
                photoURI = getUriForFile(this, "com.example.photometadata.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);

                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            }
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
```

Above code makes taken photo visible in Gallery, but of course there is no picture inside my app folder.

I can change that code to make next photos visible inside my app, but this way they will not be visible in Gallery.

I was trying to retrieve photo file from gallery and save it to getExternalStorageDir() folder in onActivityResult, but got EACCESS SecurityExeption. I tried something else, but nothing works as I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> File directory = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

The directory `getExternalFilesDir()`is an app specific directory.

It cannot be scanned by the MediaStore.

And as Gallery apps mostly query the MediaStore for images they will not see them then.

Store them at a different place and or in a different way.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I do understand that method getExternalFilesDir() return privite app directory, and it is not reacheble for MediaScanner. I just can't  understand for now how to store photos at different place or in a different way. Can you provide any code? Or link to working example?

Comment: Start with trying to save image file in `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_Pictures)` or in your own subdir of that directory..

Comment: Ok, I made it, thanks a lot! If it is not difficult for you can you tell me where can I start to make it "in a different way"?

Comment: You could use the MediaStore  insert() metod to obtain an uri which you can use to write a picture to. Mmmm.. I see that you already use the MediaStore... Had not seen that before ;-)

Comment: Yes I tried MediaStroe.insert(), and it become visible in gallery, but I have no idea how to retrieve it inside my app.

Comment: `photoURIQ = getContentResolver().insert` Use that obtained uri.

Comment: Yes, I got that, but my problem is that I don't understand how to get photo file from that uri in onActivityResult to show it inside my app (

Comment: imageView.setImageUri(photoURIQ); To read the file from stream: InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(photoURIQ);

Comment: Thank you! I feel myself uncomfortable  with too many questions, but in this way how can I retrieve all that photos after user close and start my app again?

Comment: If you dont wanna save all those uries but saved the files in your own directory then you can query the media store for files in that directory. Then you have your uries back.

Comment: Thank you @AlexRmcf and @blackapps; this gave me the information I needed to solve this!